# Query to replace last occurrence in postgres 8.3

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to write a query to replace only the last occurrence of the `()` to blank? I tried `regexp_replace` but can't get it to work properly. Thanks for any help.

Before:

```
value = sdfsdfdfs( 1m 9s )dfgd( 1m 9s )ddd( 5m 19s )

after - removed ( 5m 19s ): 

value = sdfsdfdfs( 1m 9s )dfgd( 1m 9s )ddd
```

Here is the query: I think `*` is a wildcard and I have use `\` as an escape. Not sure if this is correct but I am very confused about how to identify the proper regex.

```
select regexp_replace(value, '\*\\(*\\)', '')
```

Comment: Are you really using Postgres version 8.3? That is 8+ years past EOL.  Also show the actual query you ran and add as update to your question.

Comment: This seems like a regexp problem. To @adrian's comment - please update your question with the actual queries and a few examples of what you're matching (even a link to a regexp test website). I don't have 8.3 locally nor do I know all the possible variations of what your data may have, but i'd guess something like `/\(\s\d+m\s\d+\s\)$/` or even just `/\([^)]+\)$/` would be the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
          'sdfsdfdfs( 1m 9s )dfgd( 1m 9s )ddd( 5m 19s )',
          '^(.*)\([^)]*\)(.*)$',
          '\1\2'
       );

           regexp_replace           
════════════════════════════════════
 sdfsdfdfs( 1m 9s )dfgd( 1m 9s )ddd
(1 row)
```

To explain the pattern:

- match the start of the string (`^`)
- match as many characters as you can, so we replace the last parentheses, and capture the matched string (`(.*)`)
- match an opening parenthesis (`\(`)
- match as many characters that are not a closing parenthesis as you can (`[^)]*`)
- match a closing parenthesis (`\)`)
- match and capture everything up to the end of the string (`(.*)$`)